# Configuring JBoss to create one process per http session?

Tags: java, servlets, jboss, java-native-interface

In a web application I am developing, I am using a third party Java library (JPL) that uses JNI to connect to an external application: a Prolog engine.

For the nature of my problem, I need to have one Prolog engine per http session. But as far as I know the library I am using only let me work with one Prolog engine per java VM.

In order to solve this issue I came up with the idea of trying to configure JBoss to launch a new process (instead of just a new thread)  per each http session, a bit like CGI where normally one process is started per http request.

In this way, certain servlets could use the required JNI based library without having to worry about synchronization issues in its side, since as I expect (and hope not be wrong about that), each of them will have an independent Prolog engine with different state (e.g., different asserted Prolog facts).

Is possible to configure JBoss (or other servlet container) in this way? Any feedback or pointer will be highly appreciated!.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge this is not possible. However looking at the documentation http://www.swi-prolog.org/packages/jpl/java_api/high-level_interface.html#Multi-Threaded%20Queries the only problem seems to be that you can have only one *open* query per VM.

Comment: Hi @Philippe!, the problem is that I need to assign to each session a different state in its Prolog engine (e.g., a different set of asserted Prolog facts) depending on the user interaction. This state needs to last the entire duration of the http session. So having just one Prolog engine for everybody seems to be far from ideal.

Comment: How do you interact with the engine? Do you create new `Query` objects? Do you keep old `Query` objects around?